# How to also retrieve row/record count from following DB2 query?

Tags: sql, db2, record, rowcount

Need to also select the total record count given the following query. How would I go about doing this?

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.Creator AS TABLE_SCHEMA, t.Name AS Table_Name, c.Name AS COLUMN_NAME, 
c.COLTYPE AS DATA_TYPE, CASE WHEN c.KEYSEQ = 1 THEN 'Primary Key' ELSE NULL END AS CONSTRAINT_TYPE, NULL AS DATA_PRECISION, NULL AS DATA_SCALE 
    FROM SYSIBM.SYSTABLES t 
        INNER JOIN SYSIBM.SYSCOLUMNS c ON c.TBNAME = t.Name
    WHERE t.Creator='MY_SCHEMA_NAME' AND t.Name='MY_TABLE_NAME'
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: Do you mean in a programming language or just by SQL?

Comment: How do you want to get the total record count exactly? In an additional column with the same value for all rows? Somehow else?

Comment: Do you want to get the number of tables your query returned? Or the number of rows **in** each of those tables?

Comment: @Mark Barinstein - yes, an additional column with the same value for all rows.

Comment: @a_horse_woth_no_name number of rows in each of those tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any `SELECT` statement including your one:

```
SELECT T.*, COUNT(1) OVER() AS ROW_COUNT
FROM
(
SELECT DISTINCT t.Creator AS TABLE_SCHEMA, t.Name AS Table_Name, c.Name AS COLUMN_NAME, 
c.COLTYPE AS DATA_TYPE, CASE WHEN c.KEYSEQ = 1 THEN 'Primary Key' ELSE NULL END AS CONSTRAINT_TYPE, NULL AS DATA_PRECISION, NULL AS DATA_SCALE 
    FROM SYSIBM.SYSTABLES t 
        INNER JOIN SYSIBM.SYSCOLUMNS c ON c.TBNAME = t.Name
    WHERE t.Creator='MY_SCHEMA_NAME' AND t.Name='MY_TABLE_NAME'
) T;
```

Answer (score 0):

> Need to also select the total record count given the following query.

The `SELECT DISTINCT` seems superfluous.  The system tables should not have duplicates.  If you are getting duplicates, it is probably because the `JOIN` conditions are not complete -- you should join on both the table name and creator.

So just use `COUNT(*)`

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM SYSIBM.SYSTABLES t INNER JOIN
     SYSIBM.SYSCOLUMNS c
     ON c.TBNAME = t.Name AND
        c.TBCREATOR = t.TBCREATOR
WHERE t.Creator = 'MY_SCHEMA_NAME' AND
      t.Name = 'MY_TABLE_NAME';
```

Comment: I want to still be able to select the other values I need from the same query though

Comment: @weovibewvoibweoivwoiv . . . That is not what your question is asking.  This answers the question that you actually asked.  You can, however, add `count(*) over ()` to the fixed query (with the right `join` condition) to add an additional column with the count.